# Bootstrap 4 Accordion Toggle All

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, bootstrap-4

I am trying to toggle the state of *all* accordion items by clicking a button. By default I want them all to be closed. The button should either `Open All` or `Close All`.

According to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#collapsetoggle) I should be able to use the `toggle()` method?

I have included my current code below with a fiddle link.

**HTML**

```
<button id="toggleAccordions" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse">Open / Close</button>

<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('#toggleAccordions').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#accordion .collapse').collapse('toggle')
  })
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/org5cyr9/).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `hide` instead of `toggle`: https://jsfiddle.net/org5cyr9/5/

Comment: you can only open one accordion at a time

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek it seems ok to me, but perhaps I've misunderstood what you're attempting to do.

Comment: You could toggle class `show` but you won't get transition https://jsfiddle.net/aeoe03me/1/

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I'm confused then, as your original code is doing that. Note that, as Jerry mentioned, you can only have one accordion open at a time, if that's the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an exact answer for your code, but a generall idea of sollution that worked for me with accordion on Bootstrap 4.

The accordion is built so only one panel can be shown at the time, so the trick is to override this behavior by first remove the data-parent attribute on show and re add it on hide.

In this case I have two buttons. One for show and one for hide.

```
 $(function() {
    $('#toggleAccordions-show').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#accordion .collapse').removeAttr("data-parent");
        $('#accordion .collapse').collapse('show');
    })
    $('#toggleAccordions-hide').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#accordion .collapse').attr("data-parent","#accordion");
        $('#accordion .collapse').collapse('hide');
    })
});
```

Comment: Works Perfectly on Bootstrap 4! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
  $(function() {
  $('#toggleAccordions').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#accordion .collapse').toggleClass('show');
  })
});
```

Comment: This is correct short answer if you have a single toggle button like 'Show/Hide all' for multiple collapse inside an accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Turbojohan's response it could be written a bit shorter so that you don't have duplicate jQuery selectors:

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggleAccordionShow').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#accordion .collapse').removeAttr("data-parent").collapse('show');
    });
    $('#toggleAccordionHide').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#accordion .collapse').attr("data-parent","#accordion").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers from Turbojohan and user315400 could be improved for using only one button to show and hide the cards:

```
$("#toggleAccordion").click(function(){
  if ($(this).data("closedAll")) {
    $('#accordion .collapse').removeAttr("data-parent").collapse('show');
  }
  else {
    $('#accordion .collapse').attr("data-parent","#accordion").collapse('hide');
  }

  // save last state
  $(this).data("closedAll", !$(this).data("closedAll")); 
});

// init with all closed
$("#toggleAccordion").data("closedAll", true);
```